# How to only show one colour in a corner of a resource column in FullCalendar.io timeline view?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm using [FullCalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io) and trying to get the colours work as I planned. My goal is to get the top colour *(cyan/green)* to fill the top-left corner completely, instead of it sharing it with the left colour *(light green and red)*.

[image: Group column]

```
const resourceColumns = [
  {
    labelText: 'Ryhmät', // groups in Finnish
    field: 'title',      // gives the group name and amount of people (10 ppl)
    render: function( resource, el ) {
      el.style.borderTop  = `solid 17px ${resource.extendedProps.color}`;  // group colour
      el.style.borderLeft = `solid 17px ${resource.extendedProps.status}`; // active colour
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: are you already using some custom CSS to get this border effect in the first place? I can't reproduce it using the standard fullCalendar theme. Actually though, what version of fullCalendar are you using?